# Parsing Multidimensional JSON Array and Attach to ListView in xamarin.froms

Tags: json, xamarin, json.net, xamarin.forms.listview

I am trying to parse the JSON that has multiple objects. I am trying to parse this json and set it to my custom ListView.

I have tried This

My JSON:

```
    [
    {"Product":"Product 1",
    "Origins":
    [
        {"Origin":"XXX QQ",
        "Details":   
        [
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}
        ]
        },
        {"Origin":"ADAMI Oil",
        "Details":   
        [
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}
        ]
        }       
    ]
    },
    {"Product":"Product 2",
    "Origins":
    [
        {"Origin":"YYY pp",
        "Details":   
        [
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}
        ]
        },
        {"Origin":"PQR CCC",
        "Details":   
        [
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"},
            {"Seller":"Name","Seller_Rate":"256","Saller_QTY":"20","Buyer":"Name","Buyer_Rate":"256","Buyer_QTY":"20"}
        ]
        }       
    ]
    }
]
```

My Object Class:

```
public class Products
{
    public List<Origins> ListOrigin{ get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT { get; set; }
    public List<Products> product_list { get; set; }
    public Products() {
        product_list = new List<Products>();
    }       
}
public class Origins
{
    public string Origin { get; set; }
    public List<Details> ListDetails { get; set; }

}
public class Details
{
    public string Seller { get; set; }
    public string Seller_Rate { get; set; }
    public string Saller_QTY { get; set; }
    public string Buyer { get; set; }
    public string Buyer_Rate { get; set; }
    public string Buyer_QTY { get; set; }

}
```

And my call to the web service where i get JSON as i have shown.

```
public async Task<List<Products>> getProductsJson()
    {
        List<Products> res;
        Log.Debug("Login", "in get products");
        string responsejson = await client.GetStringAsync(Constants.url_getproducts);
        Log.Debug("Login", responsejson);
        res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Products>>(responsejson);
       /* foreach(Products p in res)
        {
            Log.Debug("Login1", p.PRODUCT);
            foreach(Origins o in p.ListOrigin)
            {
                Log.Debug("Login1", o.Origin);
            }
        }*/
        return res;
    }
```

Here i have tried to print it in the log but it throws error and gets hanged.
this is how i have accessed the all data and list on the cs. page

```
List<Products> result = await App.RestService.getProductsJson();
        //Log.Debug("Login",result[0].OriginsObj.Origin);
        list_data.ItemsSource = result;
```

On the ListView I have tried to bind the data as:

```
<ListView x:Name="list_data"  HasUnevenRows="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <!--<TextCell Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="Purple" Detail="{Binding Description}" DetailColor="Black"/>-->
                    <!--<ImageCell Text="{Binding Topic}" TextColor="Purple" Detail="{Binding Description}" DetailColor="Black" ImageSource="{Binding ImageSource}" />-->
                    <ViewCell>
                        <ViewCell.View>
                            <StackLayout Spacing="5" >
                                <Label Text="{Binding PRODUCT}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Purple"/>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding ListOrigin.Origin}" FontSize="20" TextColor="Purple"/>
                                </StackLayout>
                        </ViewCell.View>
                    </ViewCell>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
```

When i comment the for loop inside getProductsJson() method it works but. the Origin is not visible On The ListView, i know I am missing something but tired a lot not getting solution.

Comment: ListOrigin is a List of data, you need to tell it which element of the list you want to display the Origin property for

Comment: @Jason sorry i did not get you properly.. will you please elaborate what you wanted to say

Comment: Does any one know.. how to solve it..?? any solution..??